# I keep getting numberOfstops in the flightOffer API response as 0 even when there is a stop

Tags: amadeus

I am new to the Amadeus API and generally the flight business as a whole but I have set up a dev account with Amadeus and I am on a **test Plan** at the moment. I made a call to the flightOffers API thus;

```
await Amadeus.shopping.flightOffersSearch.get({myRequestPayload})
```

I got a successful response with 2 offers. However, my confusion is around the field `numberOfStops` which is 0 in the response. Please see the *segments* below as copied from the response I got;

```
"segments": [
                        {
                            "departure": {
                                "iataCode": "SYD",
                                "terminal": "1",
                                "at": "2022-11-01T11:35:00"
                            },
                            "arrival": {
                                "iataCode": "MNL",
                                "terminal": "2",
                                "at": "2022-11-01T16:50:00"
                            },
                            "carrierCode": "PR",
                            "number": "212",
                            "aircraft": {
                                "code": "333"
                            },
                            "operating": {
                                "carrierCode": "PR"
                            },
                            "duration": "PT8H15M",
                            "id": "1",
                            "numberOfStops": 0,
                            "blacklistedInEU": false
                        },
                        {
                            "departure": {
                                "iataCode": "MNL",
                                "terminal": "1",
                                "at": "2022-11-01T19:20:00"
                            },
                            "arrival": {
                                "iataCode": "BKK",
                                "at": "2022-11-01T21:50:00"
                            },
                            "carrierCode": "PR",
                            "number": "732",
                            "aircraft": {
                                "code": "321"
                            },
                            "operating": {
                                "carrierCode": "PR"
                            },
                            "duration": "PT3H30M",
                            "id": "2",
                            "numberOfStops": 0,
                            "blacklistedInEU": false
                        }
                    ]
```

From my understanding from what I have read recently about Direct, NonStops flights, this flight is definitely not NonStop since there is a stop at **MNL**.
Hence I think the **numberOfStops** should be say 2 since:

1. It is a round trip
2. For each trip, it stops at **MNL**

I am just guessing this Number based on what is apparent to me. Please correct me If I am wrong.

1. I need to understand why **numberOfStops** = 0 and not > 0.
2. Is there a way to determine the **numberOfStops** without relying on the value returned?

Thanks and I anticipate any help soonest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numberOfStops` is the number of stops planned on the segment for technical or operation purpose i.e. refueling. The API will rarely return with a value but when it does it means that a segment is flown with the same plane. This represents a scheduled stop for technical/operational purposes like for example to refuel. You can check the description of the parameter in the [specification](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-open-api-specification/blob/main/spec/json/FlightOffersSearch_v2_swagger_specification.json) file.

The API does not directly return the number of flight connections. This will need to be checked by looking at the segment size. If a segment has 2 items it means it has 2 flights. In the case of a round trip, then `itineraries[0]` contains the segments of the way to go back, and `itineraries[1]` contains the segments (flights) of the way back.